# SSL certificate config and testing

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to implement a SSL certificate for a website, I've got three questions after some research.

1) I believe i need to buy a SSL certificate and ask my host to install it. My question is do you need to alter any code for the website for the certificate?

2) Before I buy the certificate, the website is going to be built for a couple of month at least. I'm just wondering is there a developing SSL certificate I can use for the developing environment?

3) Or do I have to use self assigned certificate? If so are there any good tutorials on how to create a SSL self assigned certificate on a local machine (wamp) and a developing url site?

Thank you very much.
Sam :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, you do not need to alter any code on your website at all in order to **use** an installed SSL certificate. It is as simple as prefixing your desired destination link with the HTTPS: protocol specification instead of the typical HTTP: protocol. However, if you want to determine if your site visitor is using an encrypted page before they do something, such as submit a web form with potentially sensitive data, then depending on what you are developing your site in, you will need to detect if the current page request has been sent over HTTP or HTTPS, then if it is an HTTP requested page, you probably want to redirect the page request to the HTTPS version before proceeding.

2) Other than creating your own "self signed" certificate (more on this in #3), no your only option for a **publicly valid** SSL certificate is to obtain one from a publicly recognized Certificate Authority (CA). Long story short, a certificate of the same **key length** using the same **encryption** standard supported by your server and visitor's web browser, is no stronger or weaker regardless of vendor for purposes of encryption. So you can simply shop by price for your SSL certs. I have no affiliation with GoDaddy, but have been using them for years for public SSL certificates.

3) You certainly can create your own self signed certificate. The methods for doing this vary based on your host server and version. The limitation to a self signed certificate, is that if you go to share this with anyone, you get that warning message from your browser that the certificate is not published from a verifiable source. In most current browsers, it looks like a big scary message that something is wrong and they attempt to warn your user away from doing this. However, of course, there is certainly nothing wrong with using a self signed certificate. This is obviously true for your own development uses. Even a self signed certificate of the same key length and encryption method is as cryptographically secure as a commercially provided certificate. If you want to use a self signed certificate, just search for instruction for doing that for your server OS and version for details. Once it is installed, you will get the warning from your browser when you try to browse to a page over HTTPS. Your browser should show you an option to permanently remember and accept your self signed certificate, after which you will no longer see that warning while that certificate remains installed and valid.

Comment: Hi Dmarietta, thanks very much for your detailed explanations, it helped me to understand SSL a lot. THANK YOU! Just a couple of further questions regarding the first answer. I'm developing my site in PHP, do you mean if the site visitor typed http, the site will still go to http rather than https even though I installed SSL certificate? If so do I need to redirect http to https which I'll alter my .htaccess file? When/Where does the site know to go to https? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, if you simply just install an SSL certificate, it simply is just enabling ANY page on your site to be requested/sent in either http or https based on whichever protocol the requestor asks for. If you want to enforce certain pages to be in either one after you have installed your certificate, yes, you have to take that step yourself somehow for your site. You might do this with .htaccess in Apache or similar web servers, or in the IIS metabase for Windows IIS servers. You can also do it in code (such as PHP or any web development language/tool).